# IE 9 hangs when server replies with a huge response

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I am testing download functionality for which I have written a php script. This script reads a large file (10MB) using fopen and fread. Using fread I am reading a chunk of 10MB in a buffer and that buffer I am echoing and then flushing out using flush and ob_flush functions. So that client receives this buffer and I am able to check number of bytes received. This works fine in Chrome, FireFox and IE 8 but when I tested it in IE 9, the browser hangs and I am not able to get the proper downloaded bytes. 
Can someone suggest what are the other options that we can use to test this?

```
  define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*10240);
  $handle=fopen("10MBFile", 'rb');
  $buffer=fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
  echo $buffer;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
```

Regds

Comment: Do you test it locally with apache? Because there is a known bug with this and IE9+

Answer (score 0):

I had numerous strange hangups with IE9+ and apache and could fix it with adding this stuff into `httpd.conf`:

```
# Deal with user agents that deliberately violate open standards
#
<IfModule setenvif_module>
BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
</IfModule>
<IfModule headers_module>
RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
</IfModule>
AcceptFilter https none 
AcceptFilter http none 
EnableSendfile Off 
EnableMMAP off
```

Comment: Is there any issue related to browser buffer cache? Bcoz it won't happen with other browsers

Comment: I'm not sure, could not actually tracked it. Just worths a try. I lost a week with these hangs and found that solution which helped, but actually it was a solution for something else.

Comment: Can you specify what was the problem and what is the resolution?

Comment: Check this http://apache.igor.onlinedirect.bg//httpd/binaries/win32/ bellow there is a `Problems Installing or Running Apache 2` which mentions file upload problems. Note that Apache 2.4 does not have `Win32DisableAcceptEx` it is deprecated